# Using jquery to get selected element's value

Tags: jquery, html

Why does this not work:

HTML:

```
<img src='picture.jpg'>
<select name='blah[0]' onchange='changePicture();'>
  <option value='default.jpg'>Default</option>
  <option value='somethingelse.jpg'>A picture</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function changePicture()
{
  $(this).siblings("img").attr("src",$(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Javascript function to accept a parameter:

```
function changePicture(tag)
{
  $(tag).siblings("img").attr("src",$(this).val());
}
```

Your HTML will call the function passing it 'this':

```
<img src='picture.jpg'>
<select name='blah[0]' onchange='changePicture(this);'>
  <option value='default.jpg'>Default</option>
  <option value='somethingelse.jpg'>A picture</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, there is another this that needs to be changed to tag. I should've got there myself, I thought somewhere I had read that events could use this to reference the element that called them but obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

First you're not passing a reference to the select element in your code, so `this` has no value in your function. To do that, you'd do something like `onchange='changePicture(this);'`, but I'm not recommending that.

Since you're using jQuery you should use jQuery's event handling like this:

```
$('select[name="blah[0]"]').change(function(){
    $(this).siblings("img").attr("src", $(this).val());
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w94t8tbo/)**

Comment: I can't find the link now but somewhere I thought I had been told that with events you could use 'this' to reference the element it came from, but obviously not. It will make my code much tidier if I can use a javascript function with jquery inside and add the event in the HTML, as the [0] suggests there are an unknown number of select elements which need to change their sibling img.

Comment: _"I can't find the link now but somewhere I thought I had been told that with events you could use 'this' to reference the element it came from"_ Yes, but you need to pass a reference to the element to that function which you weren't doing. _" there are an unknown number of select elements which need to change their sibling img"_ You can change the selector to suit your needs. I just chose `$('select[name="blah[0]"]')` based on your example, but you could make it more general like `$('select')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#select").change(function() {
    var src = $("#select").val(); /* value of the current selected option */
    
    $("#img").prop("src", src);
    
    alert($("#img").prop("src"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id = "img" src='picture.jpg'>
<select id = "select" name='blah[0]' onchange='changePicture();'>
  <option value = "picture.jpg">Default Picture</option>
  <option value='default.jpg'>Default</option>
  <option value='somethingelse.jpg'>A picture</option>
</select>
```

I added 2 ids, `img` to identify the image, and `select` to identify the select. I used [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) JQuery function which is triggered when `<option>` is changed. I take the `value` of the `<option>` selected, and change the `src` of the image.

Comment: I didn't mention in the question that there will be an unknown number of select elements each with its sibling img, I hinted at it with the [0] as the name of the select statement though. I feel that this makes using ID's much more complicated than it is worth. Hence why I was using the sibling selector. Thank you for your reply though.